# Make NSXMLElement a parent

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsxmldocument

Is there a way that I can make an NSXMLElement a parent, instead of an NSXMLNode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok solved... typecasting the type seems to do the trick.

```
NSXMLNode *manufacturer = [someNode parent];
NSXMLElement *manufacturer_element = (NSXMLElement *)manufacturer;
```